# Issues installing Homestead

Tags: shell, laravel, homestead

Good day to all. I am having some serious issues installing homestead. I already have vagrant, Virtualbox, the laravel/homestead box:`vagrant box` add `laravel/homestead`. In running `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"` I get this:

```
Changed current directory to /Users/Mavericks/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing apigen/apigen (v2.8.1)
    Downloading: 100%

[ErrorException]                                                            
  ZipArchive::extractTo(/Users/Mavericks/.composer/vendor/composer/7305d654/  
  apigen-apigen-bca0954/apigen): failed to open stream: Is a directory
```

This is in my `.bash_profile`

```
#Adding Homestead PATH
export HOMESTEAD_PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin
export PATH=$HOMESTEAD_PATH:$PATH
```

I would love if someone can point me in the right direction in fixing this issue.

Comment: That's actually composer error while installing apigen/apigen package.
I'd try version to change ApiGen version in your composer  to ~4.0, since there have been some bugs for 2.8 branch. That might do it.

If that doesn't help, please show us you composer.json content.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Your computer like mine sees the home directory somewhere else. I don't know why. So to fix it. Add the line to your PATH instead of yours.

```
/Users/Mavericks/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Open a new terminal tab. And try this to check if it is working.

```
homestead --version
```

I hope it fixes your problem too.
I am using zshell so i changed the PATH at .zshrc file. Yours might be different.